# Java inner class usage to store multiple roles of a person

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

Here's a question:

I am working on a program to allocate employees in a company to different departments and establish different roles for them to the team.

**So an employee can be in multiple teams. Each team, they will have different role.**

So I created an interface `Role` and implemented into `TeamHead` class and `TeamMember` So I can establish the role for the employee once they added into the team.

However, since an employee can be `TeamHead` in Team1 and be `TeamMember` in Team2. I am not sure how to distinguish it to produce different results.

So I was thinking of creating an inner class within `Employee` class.

```
public class Employee
{
    private class TeamAndRole
    {
        Team t;
        Role r;

        public TeamAndRole(Team t, Role r)
        {
            this.t = t;
            this.r = r;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<TeamAndRole> tar;

    public Employee(){
        this.tar = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //..........
}
```

So the array list `tar` will store all the teams and roles that belong to that employee for later usage.

So is this a right approach?
If so, how do I actually implement it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: A `Map<Team, Role>` would be a more natural choice

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a map for that? (if they can only have one role within a team)

and with 2 methods for checking if the employee is within a team and which role he/she has

```
private final Map<Team,Role> roles;

public boolean isMember(Team team) {
  return roles.containsKey(team);
}

public Role getRole(Team team) {
  return roles.get(team);
}
```

ofc with error handling and nullchecks